# spring MVC jsp foreach

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

The calculate method takes two parameters, `sessionUser.getUserId()` and `user.getUserId()`,  from the list below.

I want to show the result of this method that returns a String value for each user in jsp. I use `c:foreach` to display users in jsp page.

How can I do That?

```
User sessionUser=(User)request.getSession(true).getAttribute("user");
List<User> users=groupService.getUserGroup(group); 
model.addAttribute("users",users);
for(User user:users){
model.addAttribute("result",
   calculateSililarity.calculate(sessionUser.getUserId(), user.getUserId()));
}
```

Comment: From where are you getting the `user` object, Do You want to iterate on `users` in `model.addAttribute("users",users);` and call `calculate` method for every user or what else ? Not clear with your question.

Comment: sorry I have error in posting code,I want to call calculate method for every user in users List and display user data via c:foreach with result of calculate method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

```
Map<User, String> userMap = new HashMap<User, String>();

for (User user : users) {
    userMap.put(user, calculateSililarity.calculate(sessionUser.getUserId(), user.getUserId()));
}

model.addAttribute("userMap", userMap);
```

In your JSP you would loop through the map as follows.

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${userMap}">
    User ID: <c:out value="${entry.key.userId}"/>
    Similarity: <c:out value="${entry.value}"/>
</c:forEach>
```